# Where can I find detailed info regarding Twitter4J Query strings?

Tags: java, twitter4j

Hi I have this project that I need to use Java to access twitter api, and I found Twitter4j easy to use and tried some samples from the site. However I cannot find details regarding the `Query` class regarding the query strings for this object, anyone knows a comprehensive info for this one?

Cheers.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "query strings"? Do you mean examples of things to search for?

Comment: yah, how to form query strings....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by "query string" you mean the value in the query field, that's literally any text you can type into the search box on Twitter's website. There's no list of examples because it's so wide open. Just use whatever you happen to be thinking about at that particular instant in time.

Comment: Yes correct, if this is so, then there should be at least a way to know what are the "filter" keywords to use.

Comment: Are you referring to stuff like AND, OR, etc? Go to https://twitter.com/#!/search-home and click the "operators" link under the search box. If you want a list of words to type into the box, it doesn't exist because it takes literally any string of text.

Answer (score 1):

The [related JavaDoc page](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc.html) is where I would start (select the library version your using) + searching for 'Twitter4J query examples' in Google.

Is what you need not covered in this?: http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Comment: yah, however I can't a set of sample query strings to use. Like the one from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241861/twitter4j-making-query-and-filtering-posts-by-hashtag

Comment: Well, if examples don't show up in a Google search, then they effectively don't exist (ok, that's a bit of an overstatement, I admit).